# Android maps v2 API only zoom controls are seen

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to implement an app using maps api v2 for android. 
Here is the code i am using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Main Activity is

```
package com.example.nav3;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity2 extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity2, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Manifest is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nav3"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.nav3.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.nav3.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.nav3.MainActivity2"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="my key comes here" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

On running the app though, I only see the zoom controls, but no maps is visible. Why is this so? Thanks

stack trace

```
08-24 22:58:41.482: D/AndroidRuntime(3083): Shutting down VM
08-24 22:58:41.482: W/dalvikvm(3083): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41552700)
08-24 22:58:41.502: D/dalvikvm(3083): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 285K, 4% free 9093K/9404K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
08-24 22:58:41.512: E/AndroidRuntime(3083): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-24 22:58:41.512: E/AndroidRuntime(3083): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nav3/com.example.nav3.MainActivity2}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
08-24 22:58:41.512: E/AndroidRuntime(3083):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
08-24 22:58:41.512: E/AndroidRuntime(3083):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-24 22:58:41.512: E/AndroidRuntime(3083):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-24 22:58:41.512: E/AndroidRuntime(3083):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-24 22:58:41.512: E/AndroidRuntime(3083):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-24 22:58:41.512: E/AndroidRuntime(3083):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-24 22:58:41.512: E/AndroidRuntime(3083):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-24 22:58:41.512: E/AndroidRuntime(3083):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-24 22:58:41.512: E/AndroidRuntime(3083):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-24 22:58:41.512: E/AndroidRuntime(3083):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-24 22:58:41.512: E/AndroidRuntime(3083):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-24 22:58:41.512: E/AndroidRuntime(3083):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-24 22:58:41.512: E/AndroidRuntime(3083): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
08-24 22:58:41.512: E/AndroidRuntime(3083):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
08-24 22:58:41.512: E/AndroidRuntime(3083):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
08-24 22:58:41.512: E/AndroidRuntime(3083):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
08-24 22:58:41.512: E/AndroidRuntime(3083):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
08-24 22:58:41.512: E/AndroidRuntime(3083):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
08-24 22:58:41.512: E/AndroidRuntime(3083):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
08-24 22:58:41.512: E/AndroidRuntime(3083):     at com.example.nav3.MainActivity2.onCreate(MainActivity2.java:13)
08-24 22:58:41.512: E/AndroidRuntime(3083):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
08-24 22:58:41.512: E/AndroidRuntime(3083):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-24 22:58:41.512: E/AndroidRuntime(3083):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
08-24 22:58:41.512: E/AndroidRuntime(3083):     ... 11 more
08-24 22:58:41.512: E/AndroidRuntime(3083): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment did not create a view.
08-24 22:58:41.512: E/AndroidRuntime(3083):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4769)
08-24 22:58:41.512: E/AndroidRuntime(3083):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
08-24 22:58:41.512: E/AndroidRuntime(3083):     ... 20 more
```

Comment: Please post your manifest, and please examine LogCat for any relevant errors.

Comment: @Shivam10 you don't need to use `SupportMapFragment`. Use `MapFragment`. since you min sdk is 17 and not below 12

Comment: @Raghunandan the app crashes and shows "error inflating class fragment" if i keep it as MapFragment

Comment: Have you tried searching for this issue on StackOverflow? It was asked 137 times already if I counted these correctly ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `MapFragment` not `SupportMapFragment`.

```
<fragment 
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Also you need to extend standard `Activity`

Make sure you have the right import statements

Comment: the app crashes in both these cases.

Comment: @Shivam10 you need to post the stack trace. Also you need to make the changes suggested.

Comment: yes i have changed supportmapfragment to mapfragment and fragmentactivity to activity but the app crashes in that case. The error shown is "error inflating class fragment"

Comment: @Shivam10 still not enough info you need to post the stack trace. and have you referenced google play services library project? have you followed all the steps in mentioned in the doc?

Comment: yes i have referenced the library and followed all the steps. i am posting the stack trace now

Comment: i have added the stack trace with the changes you have recommended

Comment: @Shivam10 if you have made changes suggested it should work. other than that i can't help further

Comment: @Shivam10 is your xml posted names `map.xml`? or is it `main_activity2`?

Comment: it is posted  as map.xml

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are signing application with the certificate for which API key was generated in  Google APIs Console (make sure you are using Google Maps Android API v2 not Google Maps API v2).

Make also sure that device on which you are testing your app supports OpenGL ES 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

check you are using all permissions are not
these are following permissions

```
<permission
        android:name="yourpackagename.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="yourpackagename.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
```

and also check wheather api key is valid check you device net connection.

Comment: and check wheather google play service are there are not.
com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment
use this use another device it may come on that.
if googleplay service not instaled on device it wnt come

Comment: have check google api console whether gmaps api v2 service are on ?